# JQuery fadeTo affects siblings?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fadeto

The fadeTo() function isn't working like I expect it should.

My HTML structure is this:

```
<div id="headerBlog"></div>
<div id="headerBlog2"></div>

<div id="menuBlog">
       <h1>Blog</h1>
       <ol id="nav">
           <li><a href="index.html"><img class="navButton" src="images/vcircleLeft.svg"/></a>
           <li><a href="index.html">Homepage</a></li>
       </ol>
</div>
```

The elements of *menuBlog* are displayed on the *headerBlog*.
*headerBlog* has an background-image.
Beneath the *headerBlog* is *headerBlog2*, which has also a background-image. 
Now when I try to use fadeTo() on *headerBlog,* to create a crossfade, the elements of *menuBlog* disappear suddenly and slowly fade in again. How can that happen, as they are just sibling nodes?

My JQuery code is like this:

```
setInterval(fadeBackground, 2000);

function fadeBackground() {
    var header = $('#headerBlog');
    header.fadeTo(4000, 0);
}
```

Here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ztt96da0/

Comment: Could you give us a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Yeah, here: http://jsfiddle.net/ztt96da0/

Answer (score 0):

Remember that for `z-index` to work, you will need to use either `relative` or `absolute` positioning. By not declaring these properties on both the `#headerBlog` and `#menuBlog`, the stacking order defined by your z-index will not work as intended.

Also, there is no good reason to use negative z-indexes in your example. Change the z-index to positive values, and set the `#menuBlog` z-index to the highest value for it to stay on top:

```
#headerBlog { 
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
}
#headerBlog2 { 
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
}
#menuBlog {
    height: 0px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

See working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ztt96da0/1/

Comment: Thank you very much! Didn't know the issue with positioning!